# Spring Batch Partition - partition creation taking so much time and impacting Batch job

Tags: java, spring-batch, partitioning

I am developing **Spring Batch** code. My application reads details of account from `Account` table. Usually I used to get `Accounts` in the range of 800k - 1.6 million. I need to send all these accounts to DW (Dataware House) in SQL query to get the details of AUTH, DEBIT and CLEARING from DW for each account and save those details into my DB tables.

In Spring Batch I think of using the partitions, I used code something like below:

```
<batch:step id="masterStep" next="getUniqueAccounts">
    <partition step="fetchProcessedDataForAccounts"  partitioner="accountPartitioner">
        <handler grid-size="40" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
    </partition>
</batch:step>
```

Also I used

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="40" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="40" />
    <property name="allowCoreThreadTimeOut" value="true" />
</bean>
```

**Observation** - I am getting  1.2 million accounts from query, so 12,00,000 / 40 = 30 000 partitions will be created and in a single partition 40 threads will be created. I am sending all these accounts in LIST format to IN clause.

I have seen that to create just 30 000 partitions Spring Batch code is taking around 4 hour and then queries are getting executed to DW.

Why this is happening?

Comment: Please don't use Indian words like 'lac' here. Also, guessing it was a typo, that you don't actually have 120 000 000 000 accounts

Comment: Before I suggest my solution, I would like to check if the project is open to use Store Procedure?

Comment: What version of Spring Batch are you running.  Older versions used to insert the partition records individually (not in a batch) so performance wasn't the best.  That was improved in later versions.

Comment: @  Michael Minella - Pretty late response though. I am using `3.0.7.RELEASE`

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting 1.2 million accounts from query, so 12,00,000 / 40 = 30 000 partitions will be created

You will not have 30.000 partitions (BTW it is not 30.000, it is 300.000 = 1.200.000 / 40) but only 40 partitions. You will have 300.000 items per partition.

> and in a single partition 40 threads will be created

This is not how local partitioning works. You defined a thread pool of 40 threads. Each partition will be handled by one thread and not 40 threads.

> I am sending all these accounts in LIST format to IN clause.

This IMO has big part of responsibility in your performance issue. I would recommend to use the [driving query pattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders) instead. Read only Account IDs, then with a processor look for account details and then write them to the destination table. This pattern works well with the chunk-oriented processing model.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not clear over the partitioning part yet. Could you please elaborate, still not how to implement it.